# Route53 DNS name from private VPC EC2 DNS name

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I know how to get the internal and external DNS names for an EC2 instance. What I want to know is, how do I get the Route 53 DNS name that I mapped to an internal DNS name for an instance in a VPC.

For example, say I have the following EC2 instance:

private DNS: `ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal`
public DNS: `ec2-yy-yy-yy-yyy.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

In Route 53, I give `ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal` the following name:

```
Name                      Type      Value 
node1.sub.example.com     CNAME     ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal
```

I can now ping `node1.sub.example.com` from the VPC that `ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal` belongs to. What I want to know is, how do it get the name `node1.sub.example.com` from inside `ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal`? `dig` returns `ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal`. I can get `ec2-yy-yy-yy-yyy.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` using the AWS CLI. But what command can I issue to get that other name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the strictest sense, you can't derive this value backwards.

The point of a `CNAME` is that it references a **c**anonical **name** in a many-to-one relationship.  (The canonical name, in this case, is xxx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal -- not node1.sub.example.com -- the canonical name for a host is actually the *target* of a `CNAME` record).

You can point an infinite number of names to the same `CNAME` target and they're all equally valid.  Or none, of course.

You could create `node2`, `node3`, ... ad infinitum, all pointing to the same place, and they'd all work... so, which one would be the "correct" answer in that case?  The fact that you *didn't* create more than one doesn't change the fact that you *could*, and DNS doesn't have a mechanism to resolve `CNAME` records backwards, at any rate.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the answer. What I want this name for is a docker swarm. I guess I'll tag the instances.